# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')

Tags: angular

**Issue**
The first issue it says jspdf is not a constructor, and now it comes unable to read of undefine for each any idea what is causing this issue,I'm using jspdf 2.5.1 latest
**package.json**
this is my package.json file is there any to upgrade or downgrade the version

```
{
  "name": "healthcare-frontend-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --configuration production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "~0.1202.17",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/elements": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.16",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.3",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.2.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@opentok/client": "^2.15.5",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.26",
    "angular-chat-awesome": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular-formio": "^4.11.5",
    "angular-notifier": "^4.1.1",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^3.0.4",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "google-libphonenumber": "^3.2.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.23",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.23",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.4.3",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^6.7.0",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-intl-tel-input": "^2.1.0",
    "ngx-mask": "^6.5.18",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.3.0",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^2.13.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^4.4.5",
    "ngx-scrollbar": "^7.6.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "sass": "^1.50.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "utf8": "^3.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.17",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.17",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.16",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.16",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.41",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

**code**
errors occurs in this section at this.prescriptionModel.prescriptionDetails.forEach i have no idea what is causing this issue. Am i missing any. Or is it related to any version issue

```
 downloadPDF(isSubmit:any) {        
    let doc = new jsPDF();
    let rows: Array<any> = [];
    let medicineInfo: any;
    let physicianInfo: any;
    doc.page = 1;

    var col = ["Medicine Name", "Dose", "Dispense"];
    this.prescriptionModel.prescriptionDetails.forEach((a) => {
      medicineInfo = this.masterDrugMedication.find(x => x.id == a.prescriptionId);
      rows.push(['' + medicineInfo.productName + ' ' + a.strength + ', ' + medicineInfo.route + '', '' + a.direction + '', '' + a.quantity + '']);
    });

    
    physicianInfo = this.masterStaff.find(x => x.id == this.prescriptionModel.physician);
    
    if (this.prescriptionModel.id > 0) {                 
        if (this.reportCommonData != null) {
          doc.setProperties({title: "Prescription Report"});  
          doc.setFontType("bold");
          doc.setFontSize(16);
          doc.text(15, 20, "Prescription Report");
          doc.setFontSize(10);
          
          doc.setFontType("bold");
          doc.text(140, 20, "Provider Details:");
          doc.setFontType("normal");
          doc.text(140, 25, "Name: " + this.reportCommonData.organizationName);
          doc.text(140, 30, "Address: " + this.reportCommonData.address);
          doc.text(140, 35, "Phone: " + this.reportCommonData.phone);
          doc.text(140, 40, "Email: " + this.reportCommonData.email);
          
          doc.setFontType("bold");
          doc.text(15, 35, "Patient Details:");
          doc.setFontType("normal");
          doc.text(15, 40, "Name: " + this.reportCommonData.firstName + " " + this.reportCommonData.lastName);
          doc.text(15, 45, "MRN: " + this.reportCommonData.patientMRN);
          doc.text(15, 50, "Email: " + this.reportCommonData.patientEmail);
          doc.text(15, 55, "Phone: " + this.reportCommonData.patientPhone);          
          
          doc.setFontType("bold");
          doc.text(140, 50, "Physician Details:");
          doc.setFontType("normal");
          doc.text(140, 55, "Name: " + physicianInfo.firstName + " " + physicianInfo.lastName);
          doc.text(140, 60, "NPI Number: " + physicianInfo.npiNumber);
          doc.text(140, 65, "Phone: " + physicianInfo.phoneNumber);
          
          doc.setFontType("bold");
          doc.text(15, 65, 'Pharmacy Details:');
          doc.setFontType("normal");
          doc.text(15, 70, "Name: " + this.PharmacyInfo.pharmacyName);
          doc.text(15, 75, "Address: " + this.PharmacyInfo.address1);
          doc.text(15, 80, "City: " + this.PharmacyInfo.city);
          doc.text(15, 85, "Email: " + this.PharmacyInfo.email);
          doc.text(15, 90, "Phone:" + this.PharmacyInfo.phone);
          doc.text(15, 95, "Prescription Date: " + this.datePipe.transform(this.prescriptionModel.createdDate, 'M/d/yyyy, h:mm a'));

          doc.autoTable({
            columnStyles: {
              0: { cellWidth: 120 },
              1: { cellWidth: 40 },
              2: { cellWidth: 20 }
            },
            head: [col],
            body: rows,
            startY: 100,
            theme: 'plain',
            tableLineColor: [242, 238, 238],
            tableLineWidth: 0.5,
            styles: {
              font: 'courier',
              lineColor: [242, 238, 238],
              lineWidth: 0.5
            },
          });

          doc.setFontType("bold");
          doc.setFontSize(7);
          doc.text(15,260, "Disclaimer");
          doc.setFontType("normal");          
          doc.text(15,265, "Eveda (“the Agency”) makes the information and other material (“Information”) in this document available in good faith but without any representation or warranty");
          doc.text(15,270, "as to its accuracy or completeness. The Agency cannot accept any responsibility for the consequences of any use of the Information. As the Information is of ");
          doc.text(15,275, "a general nature only, it is up to any person using or relying on the Information to ensure that it is accurate, complete and suitable for the circumstances of its use.");
          
          doc.setFontType("bold");
          doc.text(65,280,"This is a computer-generated document. No signature is required");

          doc.setFontSize(5);          
          doc.setFontType("normal");
          doc.text(180, 285,'Powered by Eveda AUSNZ Pty Ltd');

          if(!isSubmit){     
            window.open(doc.output('bloburl'))
          }else{                        
            this.fileList.push({
              data: doc.output('datauristring'), 
              ext: 'pdf'            
            });
          }
       }      
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You haven't provided enough code to be able to help, consider providing us with a minimal reproducible example. Anyways, I'm going to try the best to help you: `this.prescriptionModel` obviously is not `undefined`, so for some reason, `this.prescriptionModel.prescriptionDetails` is `undefined`.

P. s.: I will make sure to update my answer as soon as more details are provided, but currently, not enough of the code is provided to be able to provide a helpful answer